# GWAS using GAPIT3, get one error:"gapit Error in merge.data.frame......negative length vectors are not allowed"

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genetic-algorithm, gwas

I gotted one error "gapit Error in merge.data.frame(GWAS[, c(1:6, ncol(GWAS))], PWIP$PWIP[, c(1,  :
negative length vectors are not allowed", when I performed as follow code under Linux system
:

```
myGAPIT <- GAPIT(
Y=myY,
G=myG,
PCA.total=3,
model="Blink"
)
```

How to solve it?

I tried to look for similar cases used by google and microsoft copilot, but didn't get useful answers. Hoping to gain useful answers from here!